# Angular 4 - How to pass HttpParams in Http Interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I have a service that calls to the backend as follows using the new HttpClient

```
getFruits(a, b, c, d) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
       .set('apples', a)
       .set('bananas', b)
       .set('cherries', c)
       .set('dates', d);
       return this.http.get<Fruit[]>(this.GetFruits, {params});
  }
```

I'm trying to use HttpInterceptors to produce a mock backend for testing when no backend is available. I was able to get a response when I passed a set value but unable to get it to work with dynamic values.

```
if (request.url.match('http://localhost:8080/fruits/filter') && request.method === 'GET' &&
         (request.params.set('apples', '0')),
         (request.params.set('bananas', '10')),
         (request.params.set('cherries', '5')),
         (request.params.set('dates', '7'))) {
         console.log('INTERCEPTED WITH PARAMS');
         request = request.clone({url: '/assets/json/fruits.json'});
         return next.handle(request);
    }
```

This will return successfully but this like this doesn't work

```
 if (request.url.match('http://localhost:8080/fruits/filter') && request.method === 'GET' &&
             (request.params.set('apples', a)),
             (request.params.set('bananas', b)),
             (request.params.set('cherries', c)),
             (request.params.set('dates', d))) {
             console.log('INTERCEPTED WITH PARAMS');
             request = request.clone({url: '/assets/json/fruits.json'});
             return next.handle(request);
        }
```

Any help/ideas would be most appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you declare the values a,b,c and d in your interceptor?. Anyway, the request you have ALWAYS give you the response for 'apples=0, bananas=10... sorry, I don't know what are you try to do.

Comment: Do you mean you want to retrieve the a,b, c, d params (set in your service) in your interceptor? It's not really clear

Comment: Yes I would like to retrieve the a,b,c & d params (set in the service) in the interceptor.  The params are triggered by filtering and sorting methods and then goes to the backend.  I would like to intercept this call so I can produce a backendless application. The params values are dynamic.